# # in URL with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a CMS with a fully Ajaxified interface(jQuery) library. Everything happens in one index.php file via Ajax calls etc.
How can I do something like:

```
www.mysite.com/dashboard#statistics
```

when on the statistics page etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.location.hash = 'statistics';
```

Answer (score 0):

`www.mysite.com/dashboard/#!/statistics` would be better - that's the format Google propsed. http://searchengineland.com/googles-proposal-for-crawling-ajax-may-be-live-34411

Comment: Thanks for the tip, not interested in SEO as this is an internal management system, but great advice though definitely have to change some things in my projects. JS junkie here(page refresh/reload is too mainstream:)

Comment: But then there's the [trouble gawker had](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/) due to "hashbang" urls, and lots of others if you google for `hashbang url` ... not sure where I stand because of those stories.